# How to Declare Font Size Class Option

Tags: fontsize, class-options

I am creating a class with options, and desire to be able to \DeclareOption with the font size...

For example it would be nice to be able to write in the .tex file

```
documentclass[12pt]{myclass}
```

And in the corresponding mylcass.cls file write

```
\DeclareOption{\normalsize}{<some code>}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: you can look at the the code in `article.cls` where 12pt option causes `size12.clo` to be input. there is nothing special about the size options 10pt, 11pt and 12pt are just strings used as option names, not lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extending something like the article class, simply create a switch conditional after doing all your \ProcessOptions and \LoadClass{article}:

```
\ifcase \@ptsize 
  {} %if font is 10pt
\or
  {} %11pt
\or
  {} %12pt
\else
  {} %some other pt
\fi
```

If not extending a class but rather creating from scratch, then David's answer has good insight.

Note that for class article, @ptsize is merely the one's digit of the given font size, hence if your size is 10pt, you're dealing with @ptsize{0}. Thus why the switch above works: case 0 matches the 1**0**, case 1 matches 1**1**, and case 2 matches 1**2**. Also note that if you are extending extarticle, @ptsize no longer uses that definition, but rather the entire number, thus 11pt would be @ptsize{11}, so your switch statement there would need to be different

Comment: the `\else` clause can not happen if you are extending article/report/book

Answer (score 1):

The standard classes all use the following scheme.

Declare 10pt, 11pt and 12pt options

```
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
```

Make sure 10pt is default (and so `\@ptsize` is defined)

```
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}
```

process the options

```
\ProcessOptions
```

input the size option specific code

```
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
```

So if the document has `[12pt]` the file `size12.clo` is input at this point.

Comment: Thanks, however the compiler doesn't like this since I call 
`code`
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
...
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}  
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
`code`
in order to handle options that article knows to handle. The artcle.cls file begins promptly by defining \@ptsize, and thus comes into conflict with my code. If I didn't declare the initial \newcommand\@ptsize{}, then of course it doesn't exist either

Comment: @jelt if you only show fragments then it is hard to comment on code not shown. If you are loading article then you don't need to declare the options, they are already declared. If you want to do further stuff after loading article, just make it conditional on the value of `\@ptdize` which will be 0 1 or 2.

Comment: I did figure that out in a sense: I ended up making a switch-statement on \@ptsize\relax. Not sure what \@ptdize is

Comment: \@ptdize is a typo ;p

Comment: a few seconds too late to fix typo:-)

Comment: Yup, the conditional method worked. Thanks David!